# Using Netbeans to connect to remote project on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, netbeans-7, remote-access

I try to connect to my project folder on `AWS EC2` using `Netbeans SFTP`. In netbeans under Private key file I chose the .pem file what I've been getting. As host I use my AWS Public DNS and specified user, but the connection fails `Cause java.net.UnknowHostExcteption http://....`

What is the right way to connect to EC2 using Netbeans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be connecting with `http://` in your hostname.

Comment: you are right I pasted the public dns name and I did not saw that  the protocol is prefixed